# non-numeric argument to binary operator error while my data are numeric

Tags: r, binary, operators, numeric

I have following code to filter my data which is a large csv file. Running the following code, gives the error:

> Error in gedi_table[, col_index] - gedi_table$digital_elevation_model_srtm :
> non-numeric argument to binary operator" apears.

What is the solution? How can I fix it?

```
filter_gedi_table_2 = function(gedi_table, alg_num) {
  ## Function filtering GEDI table by removing shots with erroneous ground elevation  
  # gedi_table: data.frame
  # alg_num: numeric  
  # Returns a data.frame
  
  col_index = grep(paste0('elev_lowestmode_a', alg_num), colnames(gedi_table))
  
  gedi_table_filter_2 = gedi_table[-which(abs(gedi_table[, col_index] - gedi_table$digital_elevation_model_srtm) > 100
                                         & abs(gedi_table[, col_index] - gedi_table$digital_elevation_model) > 100), ]
  return(gedi_table_filter_2)
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question with a small amount of data please - just enough to reproduce the error

Comment: If `gedi_table` is a tibble rather than a real dataframe, then `gedi_table[,col_index]` will also be a tibble, not a numeric vector.  Use `gedi_table[,col_index, drop=TRUE]`.